# If $0\le a\le p$ in a von Neumann algebra then $a \in pMp$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras, projection, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra over a Hilbert space $H$ and $a \in M$ such that $a \ge 0$. Let $p\in M$ be a projection such that $a \le p$. I want to show that $a \in pMp$.
I know that, if $q\le p$ is a projection in $M$, then $q=pqp \in pMp$. But I am unable to do for any general positive element $a \in M$ such that $a \le p$. Please help me to solve this. Thank you for your time.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate.

Comment: I said "probably". Can you please search? https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3APut%20some%20formulas&p=1

Comment: @AnneBauval What do you mean "probably"? If it's a duplicate then vote to close it. If not, then why say "probably"?

Comment: "Probably" means "almost certainly; as far as one knows or can tell". I.e. I *suspect* it is.

Comment: This is not quite asked, but answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3768680/show-that-pap-is-a-c-subalgebra-of-a-c-algebra-a/3769252#3769252.

Comment: Thank you @MaoWao . Then, I vote to close as a duplicate of the post you linked to ([Show that $pAp$ is a $C^*$-subalgebra of a $C^*$-algebra $A$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3768680/show-that-pap-is-a-c-subalgebra-of-a-c-algebra-a))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, if $A$ is a C*-algebra and $p$ is a projection then $pAp$ is hereditary.

If $0 \leq a \leq p$, then $0 \leq (1-p)a(1-p) \leq (1-p)p(1-p) = 0$, so $(1-p)a(1-p) = 0$. Hence $\|\sqrt{a}(1-p)\|^2 = \|(1-p)a(1-p)\| = 0$, so $a(1-p) = 0 = (1-p)a$ and $a = pap \in pAp$.

Comment: Well done but, as MaoWao finally succeed to find, it was a duplicate.